# Kubuntu boot too slow

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I am having a slow Kubuntu boot. 
It takes 1 minute and 43 seconds.

using `systemd-analyze blame` results with:

```
    6.859s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.541s minidlna.service
      6.407s dev-sda5.device
      5.564s ModemManager.service
      4.479s accounts-daemon.service
      4.084s apparmor.service
      3.437s grub-common.service
      3.407s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.839s irqbalance.service
      2.740s ondemand.service
      2.640s systemd-logind.service
      2.555s alsa-restore.service
      2.551s rsyslog.service
      2.551s gpu-manager.service
      2.550s systemd-user-sessions.service
      2.535s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      2.462s thermald.service
      2.460s bluetooth.service
      2.456s avahi-daemon.service
      2.272s NetworkManager.service
      1.695s polkitd.service
      6.859s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                                                                                      
      6.541s minidlna.service                                                                                                                                        
      6.407s dev-sda5.device                                                                                                                                         
      5.564s ModemManager.service                                                                                                                                    
      4.479s accounts-daemon.service                                                                                                                                 
      4.084s apparmor.service                                                                                                                                        
      3.437s grub-common.service                                                                                                                                     
      3.407s wpa_supplicant.service                                                                                                                                  
      3.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                                                                                          
      2.839s irqbalance.service                                                                                                                                      
      2.740s ondemand.service                                                                                                                                        
      2.640s systemd-logind.service                                                                                                                                  
      2.555s alsa-restore.service                                                                                                                                    
      2.551s rsyslog.service
      2.551s gpu-manager.service
      2.550s systemd-user-sessions.service
      2.535s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      2.462s thermald.service
      2.460s bluetooth.service
      2.456s avahi-daemon.service
      2.272s NetworkManager.service
      1.695s polkitd.service
      1.216s systemd-udevd.service
      1.173s keyboard-setup.service
      1.054s console-setup.service
       750ms preload.service
       742ms resolvconf.service
       715ms systemd-modules-load.service
       687ms packagekit.service
       649ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       636ms setvtrgb.service
       622ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       615ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       614ms dev-mqueue.mount
       614ms dev-hugepages.mount
      6.859s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                                                                                      
      6.541s minidlna.service
      6.407s dev-sda5.device
      5.564s ModemManager.service
      4.479s accounts-daemon.service
      4.084s apparmor.service
      3.437s grub-common.service
      3.407s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.839s irqbalance.service
      2.740s ondemand.service
      2.640s systemd-logind.service
      2.555s alsa-restore.service
      2.551s rsyslog.service
      2.551s gpu-manager.service
      2.550s systemd-user-sessions.service
      2.535s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      2.462s thermald.service
      2.460s bluetooth.service
      2.456s avahi-daemon.service
      2.272s NetworkManager.service
      1.695s polkitd.service
      1.216s systemd-udevd.service
      1.173s keyboard-setup.service
      1.054s console-setup.service
       750ms preload.service
       742ms resolvconf.service
       715ms systemd-modules-load.service
       687ms packagekit.service
       649ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.859s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.541s minidlna.service
      6.407s dev-sda5.device
      5.564s ModemManager.service
      4.479s accounts-daemon.service
      4.084s apparmor.service
      3.437s grub-common.service
      3.407s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.839s irqbalance.service
      2.740s ondemand.service
      2.640s systemd-logind.service
      2.555s alsa-restore.service
      2.551s rsyslog.service
      2.551s gpu-manager.service
      2.550s systemd-user-sessions.service
      2.535s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      2.462s thermald.service
      2.460s bluetooth.service
      2.456s avahi-daemon.service
      2.272s NetworkManager.service
      1.695s polkitd.service
      1.216s systemd-udevd.service
      1.173s keyboard-setup.service
      1.054s console-setup.service
       750ms preload.service
       742ms resolvconf.service
       715ms systemd-modules-load.service
       687ms packagekit.service
       649ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       636ms setvtrgb.service
       622ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       615ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       614ms dev-mqueue.mount
       614ms dev-hugepages.mount
       558ms apport.service
       504ms ufw.service
       435ms systemd-journald.service
       396ms networking.service
       391ms upower.service
       314ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       301ms systemd-rfkill.service
       277ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
       240ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       212ms systemd-sysctl.service
       151ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       127ms sddm.service
       125ms systemd-random-seed.service
       118ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       116ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        97ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        88ms udisks2.service
        82ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-402730c9\x2dd924\x2d4ff4\x2db1b4\x2d00329db4db9b.swap
        77ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        77ms snapd.socket
        73ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        66ms pppd-dns.service
        40ms rc-local.service
        26ms user@1000.service
        23ms plymouth-quit.service
        17ms plymouth-start.service
        13ms plymouth-read-write.service
        10ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

Help me please....

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: actually its not kubuntu its kde neon but it has the same base as ubuntu - its even more light - system d blame or whatever and i saw that dev sda4 ( which is root ) causes 45 secs why?